# PHP loggin system doubt

Tags: php, logging

Im new to php and im trying to develo a loggin system, but i cant understand one thing.

For Example:

I hava a object "validator", that do some field checks. In that object i have an array where i save the errors. Like "The password you choose is not valid". Now i want to show this error to the user, the way i do it is passing this array to a Session variable. However i dont like this way of doing it. I create a new object everytime a user submits a form to validate it, but i dont know how to associate that validator object to te user. I want to say "this object belongs to that user".

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you want it to be associated to the user? Have you considered using Javascript/jQuery to validate it prior to submitting?

Comment: Well im only using php, so i didnt try it with javascript/jquery, or any other client side languages. I want to associate it because i wanna show the errors for that specific user that are saved in the object's array.

Comment: Your object system doesn't aid the application flow. Not saying it's bad, if it helps organization it's fine. However the real problem seems to be the roundtrip over the session store. Why that? Can't you output the error message right away? Try showcasing some code (keep it terse) and more importantly structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve this goal is to validate your fields with Javascript. There is a lot of tutorials on how to validate fields with Javascript on the internet.

However, if you really want to use PHP, you just need to use the POST method and reload the form's page. Then, with your PHP script, you can validate all fields with your "Validator" object.

Note that you should always validate server side everything you insert in your database. The javascript is only for the UI. Thanks maniator, I wasn't clear enought.

Jean-Philippe

Comment: dont validate with js, it can be manipulated very very very easily

Comment: You are right, but validating with Javascript is way more beautiful and user friendly. This is still important to reValidate fields server side (with a PHP script) before inserting anything in the database.